# Android expandable list view items font style

Tags: android, list, listview, typeface

I have followed the tutorial given in below link:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

How can I give custom font(typeface) to textviews in list_group.xml and list_item.xml.

I have copied Arial.ttf file into assets folder.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom textview as I have done here by overriding the TextView Class and then instead of using TextView in your xml you use CustomTextView:

```
    public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

}

@Override
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
    Typeface normalTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext()
            .getAssets(), "Esans.ttf");
    Typeface boldTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext()
            .getAssets(), "EsansBol.ttf");
    Typeface lightTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext()
            .getAssets(), "EsansLig.ttf");
    Typeface mediumTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext()
            .getAssets(), "EsansMed.ttf");
    //Modifying styles to support the different styles of custom font
        switch (style) {
        case Typeface.NORMAL:
            super.setTypeface(normalTypeFace);
            break;
        case Typeface.BOLD:
            super.setTypeface(boldTypeFace);
            break;
        case Typeface.ITALIC:
            super.setTypeface(lightTypeFace);
            break;
        case Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC:
            super.setTypeface(mediumTypeFace);
            break;
        default:
            super.setTypeface(normalTypeFace);
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is there anyway to change typeface in the mentioned example in java code

Comment: why do you want to do that when this is a simple way of doing it? but yes you can, yourTextView.setTypeFace(TypeFace.createFromAsset(Assetmanager mgr, String path);

Comment: Pontus.... Can you please edit your code. I want to use only arial.ttf. And please upload how can I use custom textview in xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to add typeface in xml

```
    public class TextViewPlus extends TextView {
private static final String TAG = "TextView";

public TextViewPlus(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setCustomFont(context, attrs);
}

public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setCustomFont(context, attrs);
}

private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewPlus);
    String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewPlus_customFont);
    setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
    a.recycle();
}

public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
    Typeface tf = null;
    try {
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: "+e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    setTypeface(tf);  
    return true;
}
```

}

in your xml

```
    <com.icl.examples.TextViewPlus
    android:id="@+id/textViewPlus1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:text="@string/info_text"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    foo:customFont="Bamini.ttf">
</com.icl.examples.TextViewPlus>
```

add this to resources, res->values-attrs.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
      <declare-styleable name="TextViewPlus">
       <attr name="customFont" format="string"/>
     </declare-styleable>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Hi Boopathi... sorry for late reply.

I want to assign arail font. So I have to give foo:customFont="Arial.ttf" in xml. Am I right?

Comment: Boopathi... I have tried above code. But I am getting error "Error parsing XML: unbound prefix" at <com.icl.examples.TextViewPlus.

What could be the problem.

Comment: @user3021918 com.icl.examples is Package Name of **TextViewPlus** Class. so change **packageName** to on which your TextViewPlus is present

Comment: I have given my package name only there. Even though I am getting error.

Comment: @user3021918 at the top of your xml file, you need to specify xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto". You should see something similar for xmlns:android at the top.